# Django: send_mail not working [only for production]

Tags: python, django, heroku, sendmail, production-environment

I'm having issues with my send_mail function in my production environment in Heroku.

My settings.py are identical for local and for production and Gmail is sending the emails correctly when I test in the localhost, but for some reason I'm getting a 500 SERVER ERROR and I'm not even getting the error logs from django in my Admin email (probably for the same reason).

I already did this before and it is really strange that this is happening. And the same gmail had already done this for the local development, so I don't think the problem is there.

I'm using Python3.6, Django1.11 and Heroku.

Here's my code:

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
from .passwords import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from .passwords import EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

from .passwords import ADMINS
MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import LandingPageMapasForm
def mapas(request):
    form = LandingPageMapasForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        # obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()

        form_empresa = form.cleaned_data.get('empresa')


        subject = '%s - Solicitação de Orçamento' %(form_empresa)
        contact_message = 'message'
        context = {}
        from_email = 'email@gmail.com'
        to_email = ['mail@geoeng.com.br']

        send_mail(
            subject,
            contact_message,
            from_email,
            to_email,
            fail_silently = False,
        )

        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://geoeng.com.br/muito-obrigado/')

    return render(request, 'mapas.html', context)
```

Comment: I don't know the reason but same thing happened to me with Django send_mail in production stuck with this problem but left it ultimately and used smtplib

Comment: I turned Debug = True on Production to see the Error and I got `SMTPAuthenticationError`
I now understand the problem. When I'm sending from local environment Gmail sees it as coming from my computer and that's ok. But when I do it in production it comes from Ashburn, VA, EUA and Gmail is not accepting that, even when I said it was me, but I never had a similar issue with other accounts.
Not sure how to fix this now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, turns out it had nothing to do with my code. Gmail was not happy with my account being accessed from Ashburn, VA, EUA (where Heroku supposedly does it's thing). So I had to play a little bit with my configurations and in the end I changed the password for a new (more secure) one and everything started to work just fine.

In short:

THE ISSUE WAS WITH GMAIL

CHANGED THE PASSWORD AND IT STARTED TO WORK